# Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded in Logistic Regression

Tags: python, statistics, logistic-regression

I am running data file load_breast_cancer() to classifify tumor. 
After running the statsmodels to examinen p-value of each variables,, there is an error:

```
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
         Current function value: inf
         Iterations: 35 

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Hope you would help me! 
Thank you! 
I tried some solution on stackoverflow about this problem, but it does not work!

this is my code:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

df = load_breast_cancer()
df_cancer = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[df['data'], df['target']], columns = np.append(df['feature_names'], ['target']))


import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as st
from statsmodels.tools import add_constant as add_constant
df_constant = add_constant(df_cancer)
df_constant.head()

st.chisqprob = lambda chisq, df_cancer: st.chi2.sf(chisq, df_cancer)
cols=df_constant.columns[:-1]

model=sm.Logit(df_cancer['target'],df_constant[cols])
result = model.fit()
```

the expected value is the result would shows the Logit Regression Results!

Comment: Hi, provide df_constant sample data please

Comment: hi, I added already! Hope you could help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Just go through this lines**

```
result = model.fit(method='bfgs')
print(result.summary())
```

Comment: but there is a warning